# Jenkins: Add project default build authorization programmatically

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I using DSLs to create my different jobs.  However, when I start up my Jenkins container, I get this error of:

```
Processing DSL script neojob.groovy
ERROR: script not yet approved for use
Finished: FAILURE
```

To fix this error, I need to select "Run as User who triggered Build under" project default build authorization, like so:

[image]
My question is how do I do that in a groovy script or in a programmatic way so my container can fully initialize Jenkins.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the generated XML, if the JobDSL plugin doesn't provide a step for this (haven't found any), then use the [`configure`](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/multibranchPipelineJob-configure) step to manually craft the XML.

Comment: Thank you.  That should do the trick.  I now have a fully automated Jenkins setup.  Life is good now!

Comment: Please post the resulting code as answer. I'd be interested in the result as well!

Comment: Hey @Gerb, would be fair to add this..

Comment: @StephenKing I added a script in my answer. Maybe it helps

Comment: I forgot to add a `.getId()` method. Added it to the script ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me the following groovy code is working to programmatically configure the [Authorize Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Authorize+Project+plugin) in Jenkins' Global Security section. I place the script in Jenkins' [init.groovy.d/](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Jenkins+upon+start+up) directory to trigger it on every start.

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.authorizeproject.*
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.authorizeproject.strategy.*
import jenkins.security.QueueItemAuthenticatorConfiguration

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

// Define which strategies you want to allow to be set per project
def strategyMap = [
  (instance.getDescriptor(AnonymousAuthorizationStrategy.class).getId()): true, 
  (instance.getDescriptor(TriggeringUsersAuthorizationStrategy.class).getId()): true,
  (instance.getDescriptor(SpecificUsersAuthorizationStrategy.class).getId()): true,
  (instance.getDescriptor(SystemAuthorizationStrategy.class).getId()): false
]

def authenticators = QueueItemAuthenticatorConfiguration.get().getAuthenticators()
def configureProjectAuthenticator = true
for(authenticator in authenticators) {
  if(authenticator instanceof ProjectQueueItemAuthenticator) {
    // only add if it does not already exist
    configureProjectAuthenticator = false
  }
}

if(configureProjectAuthenticator) {
  authenticators.add(new ProjectQueueItemAuthenticator(strategyMap))
}

instance.save()
```

Their plugin's [javadoc](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/authorize-project/) helps to know about the classes. Further, I had a look at their tests on [github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/authorize-project-plugin/blob/4b6110d3054b24b560882243b1ccdf6e4291454a/src/test/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/authorizeproject/GlobalQueueItemAuthenticatorTest.java#L93), to figure out how to configure those objects in Jenkins.

From now on I can set a job's authorization rule via the [JobDSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin) Plugin like this:

```
job("SEED/SeedMainJobs") {
  properties {
    authorizeProjectProperty {
      strategy {
        triggeringUsersAuthorizationStrategy()
      }   
    }   
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Clarification: setup from second part of the answer works by itself, it does not require first part. It was introduced in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29630

Comment: Very helpful thanks a lot. @BartBiczBoży: I still needed the first part to get it working.